# strange implementation of TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds

Tags: c#, .net

```
public double TotalMilliseconds
{
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    get
    {
        double num = (double)this._ticks * 0.0001;
        if (num > 922337203685477.0)
        {
            return 922337203685477.0;
        }
        if (num < -922337203685477.0)
        {
            return -922337203685477.0;
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

-922337203685477.5808<=ticks * 0.0001<=922337203685477.5807

why does it cut the fractional part?

pinckerman said "double has a precision of 15-16 digits". But why does TotalSeconds not cut fractional part?

```
public double TotalSeconds
{
    [__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
    get
    {
        return (double)this._ticks * 1E-07;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be that double has a precision of 15-16 digits and you're using a part of them for the integer?

Comment: @pinckerman you are right. seems I need a learning about float.

Comment: @pinckerman but why does TotalSeconds not cut the fractional part? I have edited question.

Comment: Where do you see the actual precision of double?

Comment: @pinckerman ILSpy for dotnet 4.0

Comment: The only reason I could find out is that `TotalSeconds` will reasonably need 3 digits less for the integer precision, so they can be used for the mantissa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have viewed Mono.

```
public double TotalMilliseconds
{
    get
    {
      return (double) _ticks  / TicksPerMillisecond;
    }
}
```

it seems be just a implement-specific.

Comment: I hope it's the same of:  
double num = (double)this._ticks * 0.0001;

Comment: @pinckerman 'public const long TicksPerMillisecond = 10000L;'

Answer (score 0):

You should check the type precision:
[MSDN double definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
As you can see a `double` has a 15-16 digits precision, and you're using most of it for the integer part.